# update column data in current row with the one in the previous row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge

Can anyone help me in the below execution :

I want to update RACF_ID and SUPV_RACF columns of date_value 8-JAN-2018 as
the data in RAC_ID and SUPV_RACF columns of date_value 01-JAN-2018.
Basically I want to update the data of a particular date value to the data present in the date_value of a week before.(date_value - 7).It should only update the rows with column effective_dt as null

Below is the query which I tried but failed to get output :

```
declare
cursor C1 is 

select * from temp_join;
begin
for i in C1
Loop
update temp_join r 
set r.RACF_ID = i.RACF_ID ,
r.SUPV_RACF = i.SUPV_RACF   
where  to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(i.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') -7 and
to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') > to_date('01-JAN-2018' , 'dd-mon-yyyy') and R.Effective_Dt is null ;
end Loop;
end;
```

The output which I desire to achieve vs current scenario of the table:

[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

The table

[image: CURRENT SCENARIO OF THE TABLE]

Comment: A self join is probably a better approach than a curser.

Answer (score 0):

There are no images in your message (I suppose that you planned to attach them). Anyway, a SQL like this one might do the job:

- remark A: you should join tables on something (ID, possibly)
- remark B: no need for TO_DATE if DATE_VALUE column datatype is DATE (it should be)

---

```
update temp_join r
   set (r.racf_id, r.supv_racf) =
          (select i.recf_id, i.supv_racf i
             from temp_join i
            where     i.id = r.id                       --> remark A
                  and r.date_value = i.date_value - 7)  --> remark B
 where     r.date_value > date '2018-01-01'
       and r.effective_dt is null;
```

Comment: I think correct way is "r.date_value = i.date_value **+** 7" (addition not subtraction)

Comment: "update temp_join r
   set (r.racf_id, r.supv_racf) =
          (select i.recf_id, i.supv_racf i
             from temp_join i
            where     i.id = r.id                       --> remark A
                  and r.date_value = i.date_value - 7)  --> remark B
 where     r.date_value > date '2018-01-01'
       and r.effective_dt is null;" The above query is not working.The null values are still same.Can you chech the images I uploaded in the question? It is visible now

Comment: @PratikFouzdar did you change "i.date_value - 7" to "i.date_value + 7"?

Comment: @hekko, thank you for posting a comment. I just copied what Pratik wrote in his query, and it says `to_date(r.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_date(i.date_value , 'dd-mon-yyyy') -7` >>> "- 7", not "+ 7". Though, I'm not saying that you're wrong, the OP will easily change it if necessary.